# GTM Ecommerce Data not displaying in GA4 despite "successful api call" and GA4 event triggering

Tags: javascript, e-commerce, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

any help would be appreciated. I am stumped.

I am having trouble getting my ecommerce data to report in my GA4. We have two data streams going into our GA4. One for our main site and one for handling all our subscription purchases since they are handled by an outside vendor.

We are using GTM to insert the code into the head for both our site and our vendor site, I have configuration tags for both sites. GTM makes it easy for me to insert code into the vendor ecommerce site since I don’t have direct control over that site. Our subscriptions are handled through an iframe embed on our subscribe pages and this code executes inside the iframe.

There are three GTM tags on that page and this one I am referring to executes first. I don’t think there is any need to share the code for getting the data to the dataLayer as there is no trouble there. I have two custom html events that are using the ecommerce add_to_cart event and purchase event.

I can console.log the dataLayer and see my events, I can see the dataLayer in GTM, and I can see my event that sends the api data from the dataLayer to GA4 and trigger the purchase and add_to_cart events inside of GA4. See screenshots below.

[The events firing as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlUWi.png)

[Tag details of the event that sends dataLayer data to GA4 when add_to_cart or purchase events appear in the dataLayer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgspX.png)

[DataLayer data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdgYd.png)

[The API data sent to GA4 that triggers a GA4 conversion event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIIcN.png)

[The one glaring issue other then the data got displaying in GA4 is I am not getting an actual hit event that fires for the output from GA4.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xa1fm.png)
https://sp-cdn.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/edh/Support/outputGA4.png

I can add additional data, code, info, or screenshots if needed.

Thanks for any help